# Why do wildcards behave differently for different drives?

Tags: windows, command-line, wildcards, dir

I'm using a Windows XP SP3 machine. My `Z:` drive is a mapped drive to a UNIX box.
There is a file called **`wk1_dailybackup_20110605043344.sql`** in both `z:\archive` and `c:\archive`.

At my CMD prompt from `c:\archive` the command

```
c:\archive dir *backup*
```

lists my file, but when I go to `z:\archive` and type

```
z:\archive dir *backup*
```

my file is not listed.

Questions:

1. Why do wildcards not work on the mapped drive like it does on the local drive?
2. What can I do to use wildcards on the mapped drive?

(Please don't suggest 'right-click Start, Search' to get the Poster Dog for inept searches.)

Comment: What happens if you type: `dir c:\archive\*backup*` and `dir z:\archive\*backup*` n.b. these can be run from anywhere.

Comment: Maybe it has a hidden or system attribute set. Try `dir /a z:\archive\*backup*`

Comment: Do you see the same problem with `dir *backup*.*`?

Comment: Are you *sure* there is no typo anywhere (in the filename or in the commands you type)? How did you verify that the file actually is there in both locations? Do you see it when typing just `dir` in either directory?

Comment: @Jonas, typos are irrelevant with a wildcard, that’s part of their use in the first place. Unless the word *backup* is misspelled (eg “bakup”), then it’s unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: @Synetech: exactly, I was thinking about the file being named "wk1_dailybakup_20110605043344.sql" or "wk1_dailyback-up_20110605043344.sql" or the like.

Comment: But the one in `C:` works, so would it be likely that one would be named correctly but one named incorrectly? With a filename like that, I doubt that there is any manual involvement in the filename.

Comment: @Windos: The wildcards work when I search the c: drive from both c: and z: drive. The wildcards do not work when I search the z: drive from both the c: and the z: drive.

Comment: @Jonas: I used windows copy/paste to copy from z: to c: to ensure I have the same file in both locations.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows NT, processing wildcard directory searches is the province of the individual filesystem driver.  In the case of a remote volume, it is the province of the client FSD for the network, which may or may not it its turn hand search requests over to the fileserver.

Without anything more than "It's a UNIX box.", which doesn't even narrow things down to one FSD on the client, let alone provide information about the fileserver, no-one can tell you anything more specific than that your network FSD, or possibly the fileserver that it is talking to, has decided that `wk1_dailybackup_20110605043344.sql` will not come up in a wildcard search for `*backup*`.  For all that the rest of us know, you're using network software that has wildcard processing behaviour as a configurable option.